# add a script to iframe header from parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, cross-domain

When I run the following code:

```
created_script=document.createElement('script');
created_script.src='/javascripts/jquery-1.4.2.js';
created_script.type='text/javascript';
$(document.getElementById('fancybox-frame').contentWindow.document.head).append( created_script);
```

The script element is created in the iframe's parent's head tag and not the iframe's head tag. Does anyone know how to fix this to be appended to the iframe's head tag?

Comment: make sure the parent and child are from the same domain or else same origin policy will prevent it from working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this with jQuery, I was able to execute this successfully as long as the iframe domain, protocol, and port matches. Otherwise, it was treated as an unsafe attempt to access a different url.

```
$("#fancybox-frame").contents().find("head").append(created_script);
```